# How to define container element constraint on List using programmatic API from hibernate-validator?

Tags: hibernate-validator

I am working on validation schema using programmatic approach for hibernate validator according to these instructions https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#section-programmatic-api.

I managed to validate String objects (`name`) as well as nested objects (`B`).

```
class A {
    private String name;
    private B item;
}
```

In Kotlin, I have the following configuration:

```
val hibernateValidatorConfiguration = Validation
    .byProvider(HibernateValidator::class.java)
    .configure()
val constraintMapping = hibernateValidatorConfiguration
    .createConstraintMapping()
constraintMapping
    .type(A::class.java)
         .property("name", ElementType.FIELD)
              .constraint(NotNullDef())
         .property("item", ElementType.FIELD)
              .valid()
    .type(B::class.java)
         // some validation constraints ...
```

However, I faced a challenge when I wanted to replace `B` with `List<B>` and validate all items in the list.

```
class A {
    private String name;
    private List<B> items;
}
```

How should I define this in constraintMapping?

Answer (score 0):

The keyword you're looking for is: `container element constraints`.

You have an example here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-nested-container-element-constraints .

So something like:

```java
ConstraintMapping constraintMapping = configuration.createConstraintMapping();

constraintMapping
    .type( A.class )
        .field( "items" )
            .containerElementType( 0 )
                .constraint( new NotNullDef() );
```

should work.

Comment: I see now, this feature must have been introduced with 6.1 and I have 5.3.